# Metal and Non-metal Health Wearable and body implants

Tags: halal-haram, health

Assalamwalekum,
I’m a Developer and I plan to build a smart wearable band to track health related data and analyse them using AI model. The wearable devices that I plan to build are as followed:

1. Metal or Silicon wrist band
2. Glucose meter (plastic)
3. Similar products

Apart from that, I plan to implant a microchip & a microprocessor into my body (hand) and will not be visible as it will be inside the body. Now most processors use gold but I’m seeking alternatives.

My questions are:

1. Are metal wrist band halal to everyone? If yes then which metals are halal for male and female?
2. Electronic uses Gold, Copper and other metals in their circuit boards (I will 100% avoid toxic metals like Lead and other). What about that?
3. Now for body implants, will it be halal (they will be hidden and so can’t be used for fashion purposes). Which metals will be considered Halal.

My plans are to build a Halal Health Solution (except the body implantation thing, that is only for me).
Help me out, please.

Comment: I forgot to add that the in-body implant is not for health reasons. The implantation is for me to authenticate to some highly secure servers and infrastructure which contains some seriously and highly confidential and sensitive data. The implant will allow me to verify my physical biometric presence while accessing them.

Comment: I have heard that prosthetic tooth or nose made from gold or silver are permitted because other metals corrode.